# Gradle build time too slow

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an Android project that has around 15 modules each of them is a separate GitHub project, some of the modules have interdependencies, its basically a sample client with a library that has 14 components(modules).

Every time I make a single change and re build/run it takes takes about 1 min 40 seconds on an i7 with 28GB Ram

I have tried many things to improve the build time, including the tips in this article,But I have not seen a significant change.
https://medium.com/@erikhellman/boosting-the-performance-for-gradle-in-your-android-projects-6d5f9e4580b6

it looks like  it goes through all the modules and see if they are Up to Date, which takes time, but also compiling and the dexing.

Does any one have an idea on how to improve this?

I am using Gradle plugin 1.2.3, BuildTools 22.0.1 and TaskWrapper 2.4

Answer (score 3):

I was suffering from the same problem before but as google announced in there last I/O that there is a big improvement in performance in Gradle and android studio in common.

but for me this single trick helps me a lot and reduce the time by more than 50%.

> make Gradle run offline.
>   [image]

Answer (score 1):

The next official planned release of Gradle plugin is 1.3. If you watch the talk on gradle from a presentation at Google I/O https://youtu.be/f7ihSQ44WO0?t=4m23s then Google are making claims of big performance improvements. **If** these claims prove to be true then I believe that this will be the best chance of cutting down build times for Android projects.

Currently you can use the latest beta version which is 
`1.3.0-beta4` by adding it to your `build.gradle` file. Example below:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Checking for any new beta versions can be done at jcenter https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need that all dependency update every time you run your project, I suggest you to configure gradle to work offline. You can do that in Android Studio in the Gradle tab in the Setings windows. I hope that this can help you.